# Vauxhall Astra clutch/flywheel

Tags: clutch, vauxhall

My car needs a new clutch/flywheel. I found a kit on eBay described as : LUK clutch/dual mass flywheel kit.

I'm now having the clutch fitted elsewhere, but the mechanic says that this car does not have a dual mass flywheel.

Now I don't know if it should, or shouldn't have a dual mass flywheel, and I'm hoping that someone may be able to give me a definitive answer.

The car spec is:

Vauxhall Astra Mk5 (2004 =>) 5 door, 1.8l Petrol, SRi

Comment: That eBay listing you had mentioned (If I am looking at the same one) clearly specifies it is for 1.7 CDTi (turbo-diesel) engine.

Comment: @theUg, yes indeed, but do you see where it says that it is suitable for the 1.8 petrol too? Maybe that is just the clutch component, not the flywheel.

Comment: Not on [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/VAUXHALL-ASTRA-H-MK5-LUK-DUAL-MASS-FLYWHEEL-CLUTCH-KIT-CSC-1-7-CDTi-Z17DTH-5-SPD-/170904684325), no. I would at least shoot a message to the seller. There is possible after-market application, but reading VW forums about using MDF Luk instead of SMF Sachs on TDi models, many said that there isn't much difference any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely the dual mass flywheel you found was for the diesel Astra. Some petrol engined cars do use them, but the Astra isn't one of them. Even if it was, failure of a petrol flywheel is very rare anyway - are you positive you need a new flywheel?

Regardless, you should trust your mechanic or not use them at all. This sounds like a straightforward clutch change to me.

Source: Checked parts suppliers and there is no DMF listed for your car

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the type of answer I was looking for! The mechanic says there was no damage to the existing flywheel (not d/m) so it has not been replaced, however the clutch has been replaced. along with a full gearbox strip down and recon.

Comment: @series0ne Excellent - glad to hear it was sorted.

Comment: Indeed, DMF is used on 1.7 CDTi model of Astra (turbo-diesel).